# Pentaho Row Denormaliser Step Not Working

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, pdi

I have some sorted data that I'm trying to denormalize but the step in Pentaho isn't working correctly.

Here is a snapshot of the **sorted** data:

[image: Sorted Data]

And here is a snapshot of the Row Denormaliser Step as I've configured it:

[image: Row Denormaliser Step]

What I get is:

[image]

There are no steps between the sorted data preview and the Row Denormaliser Step. I've also made sure that the field type of 'Number' is consistent with the field type of the output field of the previous step.

What am I missing/getting wrong? Any ideas as to why it's not working?

**EDIT**

I took a Data Grid step and input the data exactly the same as the output of the Table Input step - and it worked fine! But with the Table Input step, it breaks. Here are the screenshots:

1) With the Table Input:

Transformation:

[image]

Table Input Step's Data:
[image]

Final Output:
[image]

2) With the Data Grid Step:

Transformation:

[image]

Data Grid Step's Data:

[image]

Output:
[image]

I've hit a roadblock and don't understand how the table input step could be breaking the transformation. If anyone has any insight, please share!

**Edit 2: Further Testing**
My database connection is that of an MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express for the original issue. I have now tested the following:

- Similar architecture for a PostgreSQL Server (2 groupings on the normaliser step): SUCCESS
- Single grouping on the MS SQL Server with the original field types (without Select Values Step) as 'String': FAILURE

It seems that this issue is localized to the use of a MS SQL Server connection. Creating a blocker JIRA ticket now on Pentaho - hopefully someone on the team will be able to reproduce the bug(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused due to extra spaces being padded on the cells, which the Row Denormaliser couldn't parse against correctly. Upon trimming the cells using the String Operations step, the transformation now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the data types of the columns in the Table Input step are different from those specified in the Data Grid step, which might lead to conversion errors in the Row Denormaliser. Make sure in your Select Values that you are specifying the types of all used fields, hopefully that will ensure exactly the same data is going into the Sort Rows whether it comes from the Data Grid or Table Input step.

Comment: I've already verified that the types are all 'String'. That's what the Select Values step in my transformation is for. I've mentioned it in my original post.